# Difference between API and IDL

Tags: api, idl

Both API and IDL act as an interface between two components of software and play the role of bridge between two components of software or between two software.

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`API` is a concept. It is any external programming interface that a piece of software exposes so that it can accept external input from some other software, run some logic, and provide output. Usually when we talk about API's, like Facebook's Graph API, or the Windows API, we are talking about the types and logic contained within those API's, and how they can be used.

`IDL`, as the tag says, is a language you can use to describe a API, in a manner that other software may understand. It is platform independent, so can be used to facilitate integration. More information about this language is vastly available if you search for it ;)

Comment: means API can get data from other software and perform some logic and return some output while IDL is the way to get data from other software or help two software to communicate with other and platform independent..Am I right?

Comment: Almost 100% right. You are right when you talk about API's. But as for IDL, it's not the way to get data from other software. It's one language that can describe API's to other software. The rest of your sentence is correct.